# Python XOR operator on hex values

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, xor

I'm trying to figure out how take the XOR of every byte in my string:

```
string = "\xa3\xb4\x55"
```

with 100000 (binary). How would I do this in python? I've tried doing this:

```
newString = ""
for n in string:
    new = n ^ 0x20
    newString.append(new)
```

I need the output of newString to look like

```
output = "\x83\x94\x75"
```

but i'm currently not getting that :-( any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert each character to its charcode, then perform the xor on the charcodes. After that you then convert the result back to a character, which results in something like this:

```
string = "\xa3\xb4\x55"

newString = ""
for n in string:
    new = chr(ord(n) ^ 0x20)
    newString += new

print(newString)
```

[Here's a working example](https://eval.in/730511)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert to number using `ord(..)` and then back to a character using `chr(..)`.

```
>>> "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ 0x20) for x in "\xa3\xb4\x55")
'\x83\x94u' # 'u' => '\x75'
```